# Should I scale high ranging ordinal fields?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-scaling

In the left column, I have an ordinal integer field.
In the right column, I have a scaled float feature.

Should I scale the ordinal field since it is getting so much bigger than the other feature?

[image]

Comment: scaled float feature. Would you elaborate what could be understood from it?

Comment: Left column does not seem to convey  the idea of  any Scaling. A substantive description is needed.

Answer (score 0):

*We scale data because certain algorithm will not work optimally esp. Gradient descent.
You may check the internet for further detail.*

Coming to the exact question -

I am assuming, you have done the analysis that the Oridinal feature will be used as a Continuous(Not Categorical) feature with its respective values. So, I will ignore this point

Models don't see the feature scale, it looks for the respective variance, interaction with other features, Correlation with the target etc.(*in a very simple language*) and scaling will not hamper these parameters.

So, you must scale if that is your only concern.

 You may ignore it for some Models e.g. Decision Tree/RF will work fine even without scaling.